# On a weak notion of sheaves on topological spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

First of all, I give my definition of weak sheaves:

> By a **weak sheaf** on a topological space $ X $, we mean a presheaf
>   $F$ such that for all open covering $\{ U_i\}_{i\in I} $ of $X$ sheaf
>   condition holds; that is, the diagram
>   \begin{equation*}  
>  F(X)\stackrel{}{\rightarrow} \prod_{i\in
>  I}F(U_i)\stackrel{}{\rightrightarrows}\displaystyle\prod_{(i,{i'})\in
>  I\times I}F(U_i\times_XU_{i'})   
> \end{equation*} is an equalizer.

**Notice that this condition for other open subsets of $X$  is not necessary. While for a sheaf this condition holds for every open subset $U$ of $X$ and all open coverings $\{ U_i\}_{i\in I} $  of $U$.**

---

**Update 1**: Clearly, every sheaf is a weak sheaf, but not conversely. As an example, if $S=\{0,1\}$, then the constant presheaf with the value $S$ on a non-empty space is a weak sheaf but not a sheaf.

---

Consider weak sheaves as a full subcategory of the category of presheaves.

Now my questions are

> **(1)** Does the category of "weak sheaves" constitute an (elementary) topos? or at least which properties of the category of sheaves are
>   true for that of "weak sheaves"?
>
> **(2)** Is the category of "weak sheaves" of abelian groups an abelian category?

In sheaf theory, these properties are obtained by a tool called sheafification. So I think we should have a reflection from presheaves to weak sheaves. But I don't know if there is such a reflection. Maybe another idea works as well!

---

**Update 2**:
I don't know if it is possible to discuss a similar situation over a site, (say on a final object of the site, if it exists), or as David Roberts mentioned in comments, consider a fixed object $X$ in the site and only $X$ itself has nontrivial covering families (probably).

One motivation for this question is that you are still able to survey local problems by weak sheaves, mainly about the whole space. For example, local solutions of differential equations in de Rham cohomology by the Poincare lemma. But what is the need for these solutions to open submanifolds, as a sheaf does?
I am aware that this gives rise to a resolution of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{R}}$, and then isomorphisms between de Rham cohomology and singular, Cech, Alexander-Spanier cohomologies on manifolds.
But I don't believe these are admissible answers.

**In fact, I want to know why we need to strengthen "weak sheaves" to the notion of sheaves.**

---

**Update 3**:

Every sheaf is an assignment of a weak sheaf to each open subset of the space.

---

I am interested in a clear explanation.

Comment: What happens if you take the open cover to consist of all open sets of $X$? I'm pretty sure a weak sheaf as you define it is a sheaf, but I'd like to see what you are taking as the definition of a sheaf.

Comment: @ David See update. In the definition of a sheaf you have to verify the condition above for every open subset, not only the whole space, as a space and its open coverings separately. However, in weak sheaves, it is enough to check the condition for the whole space.

Comment: What's the motivation behind this definition? The sheaf condition has to hold because sheaf theory is about solving local problems, not simply because people wanted an abelian category for no reason. Do you have natural examples of weak sheaves that are not sheaves (by natural, I mean an example that you thought of before writing down this definition, for example).

Comment: @Najib I think there was a mistake in the last part. I should have written "these problems". But I am interested in the answer of the second problem. Actually, I meant that a tool that implies these nice properties of the category of sheaves is the "sheafification".

Comment: Moreover, I think the constant presheaf is a natural example

Comment: I have edited the question again.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I don't think there is a site structure on the lattice of opens of $X$ such that only $X$ itself has nontrivial covering families as in the condition, but all other sets have no covering families. So weak sheaves are probably not a reflective subcategory of presheaves, else you'd get such a site structure, I think.

Comment: @ARA I'm pretty sure that sheaves predate toposes, and that in fact sheaves are the motivation for toposes, not the other way around.

Comment: @ Najib Of course I am familar with sheaves and (Grothendieck and elementary) topoi.

Comment: As you know, sheaves are not the only example of topoi, but the category of presheaves is also a topos.

Comment: My point is that if sheaf condition restricts to the definition of weak sheaves, the result is not intersting (I guess!). Any way, is there an explanation.

Comment: @ Najib Historicaly I mean when leray defined sheaves or even earlier.

Comment: @ Najib By weak sheaves you are able to survey local problem, mainly about the whole space. For example, local solutions of differential equations in de Rham cohomology by the poincare. But what is the need for this solutions to open submanifolds, separately, as a sheaf does?

Comment: Sheaves are nice because the category of such is a left-exact reflection of a category of presheaves, where all structure is pointwise and so inherited from $Set$, or something along those lines :-)

Comment: So is it possible to have such a reflection from presheaves to weak sheaves?

Comment: Such a reflection is equivalent to a Lawvere-Tierney topology on the category of presheaves, which I'm pretty such is equivalent to a site structure on the category arising from the lattice of opens.

Comment: @ David Do you mean that the existence of a reflector from presheaves to weak sheaves is equivalent to existence of a Lawvere-Tierney topology on the category of presheaves?

Comment: I got it right?

Comment: @ARA a lex reflector on any topos (eg a category of presheaves) is equivalent to a L–T topology, yes.

Comment: @David On the other hand, we have a reflector from presheaves to sheaves. So there exists an L–T topology!?  I'm really confused!

Comment: there can be many L–T topologies on a given topos. The identity reflector always gives one, for instance. Just as there can be different Grothendieck topologies on a given category (yes, even when that is the lattice of opens of a space, if the space is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331973/on-a-weak-notion-of-sheaves-on-topological-spaces?noredirect=1#generic enough).

Comment: @David Thanks for your helping

Comment: @ARA no worries :-)

Comment: Regarding your update 2 - think about holomorphic functions on domains in $\mathbb{C}$, or, better, on a compact Riemann surface. It's not sufficient to consider global functions.

Comment: Another example of why you want the full sheaf property even if you're interested in global sections is the following: if we have a section $s\in F(X)$, you might want to define its support as the complement of the biggest open $U$ where $s|_U=0$. However I don't know how to prove the existence of the latter without the full sheaf property.

Comment: Have you tried doing this on a three point discrete space? This is probably the easiest example where there are multiple truly distinct nontrivial open covers of $X$, and it seems hard to force the weak sheaf condition on all covers simultaneously. (Specifically, I think that the category of weak sheaves might not be cocomplete, for example.)